# How to check dirty or pristine in Angular 5 modal form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular6, angular5

I am working in a form in a modal. I want to submit form only if the there are any change made to the form field. My form looks like below:

### HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" *ngIf="productForm"
(ngSubmit)="submitUpdatedRecord(productForm.value)">

    <input
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    formControlName="product_code" 
    name="product_code_clip"
    placeholder="Enter Product Code Clip"
    [(ngModel)]="editProductData.product_code" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-update" [disabled]=!productForm.valid>
    UPDATE
    </button>
</form>
```

### TS

```
submitUpdatedRecord(formData: NgForm) {
        console.log(formData.dirty);
        return false;
```

I did ng-pristine check in Angular JS but I am not sure how to implement it with Angular 5?

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a mix of Reactive and Template driven forms. I am not sure why you need `[(ngModel)]`. `pristine` and `dirty` are also available in Angular 5+. But you need to access it from your form group.

```
submitUpdatedRecord() {
   console.log(this.productForm.pristine);
}
```

FormGroup extends AbstractControl. You can find more information about available properties [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl).

Answer (score 0):

This person created a recursive function, that helped me to trouble shoot some unknown nested fields I was working with, with which were dirty.

Here's the reference to their web page:
https://www.usefuldev.com/post/Angular%20Forms:%20how%20to%20get%20only%20the%20changed%20values

Here's the code snippet (slightly refactored for ease of use):

html

```
{{ "_myForm.pristine: " + _myForm.pristine }}
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px">
  {{ this.getUpdates(_myForm) | json }}
</div>
```

typescript

```
getUpdates(formItem: FormGroup | FormArray | FormControl, updatedValues: any = {}, name?: string): any {
    if (formItem instanceof FormControl) {
      if (name && formItem.dirty) {
        updatedValues[name] = formItem.value;
      }
    } else {
      for (const formControlName in formItem.controls) {
        if (formItem.controls.hasOwnProperty(formControlName)) {
          const formControl = formItem.controls[formControlName];

          if (formControl instanceof FormControl) {
            this.getUpdates(formControl, updatedValues, formControlName);
          } else if (formControl instanceof FormArray && formControl.dirty && formControl.controls.length > 0) {
            updatedValues[formControlName] = [];
            this.getUpdates(formControl, updatedValues[formControlName]);
          } else if (formControl instanceof FormGroup && formControl.dirty) {
            updatedValues[formControlName] = {};
            this.getUpdates(formControl, updatedValues[formControlName]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return updatedValues;
  }
```